# matplotlib: Cannot import name _tkagg

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, user-interface, matplotlib, tkinter

I have been searching for days to solve this problem, found dozens of solutions, tried them all, but still not working. 
Trying to do this import to use the `Tkinter`:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg
```

However, it throws an `ImportError` every time.

MAC: OS X El Capitan 
Python 2.7 
IDE: Spyder of Anaconda/ Eclipse

I uninstalled/installed `matplotlib` several times, and confirmed that the backend is set to `TkAGG` and nothing helped.

How could I solve this issue?

**Edit** 
During my search, I found this problem is quite common, so I may update this question to include some solutions I found and why they didn't work.

[1] [TkDocs](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html) 
I read this documentation, and from what I understood here, is that the solution it offers it's limited to Python 3, however, the `TkAGG` is working fine with Python 2.7 on Windows.

Comment: Are you able to produce a normal matplotlib plot using the "TkAgg" backend without importing "matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg" yourself?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have tried it with the following example
[user_interfaces example code](https://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html) and it didn't work as well (gave the same error message). So I would say No, I can't produce a plot using `TkAgg`. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: This was to find out if whether matplotlib doesn't find Tkinter at all. So this might be complete independent of matplotlib and it may be that you don't have Tkinter installed; what happens if you try `import Tkinter`? If that fails as well, try to (re)install Tkinter, or, if possible complete Python (as Tkinter should be part of it).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest `import Tkinter` works fine with a `Hello World!` script. I have to mention that it works fine when running from terminal or Eclipse, while when using Spyder it just freezes.

Comment: But using matplotlib TkAgg fails even from terminal?

Comment: Wow! It just worked now from terminal! I don't know exactly what was the turning point. However, still freezing in Spyder, and throwing `ImportError: Gtk3 backend requires pygobject to be installed.` in Eclipse.

Comment: This is confusing, since Gtk shouldn't be part of the game at all. Maybe at this point you may collect what you found out due to comments and edit the question to reflect this in a coherent manner. (The issue should be understandable without reading the comments.) But if everything is working as expected from terminal, looking into some specific settings in the IDEs you're using might be the next step.

Comment: Did you have any luck resolving this problem?

Comment: @DanielR.Livingston Not at all! Are you facing the same problem or have a solution for it?

Comment: @philippos Exact same problem, unfortunately :(